# Why does a parameter become False instead of None at runtime in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a PyQt application and have encountered an issue where a parameter seems to be evaluated as `False` at runtime rather than `None`. Here's a snippet of the code:

```py
def createMenu(self):
    """Overrides Main menu"""
    super().createMenu()
    action = QAction('Import to MyPlugin', self, triggered=self.importFileToMyPlugin)
    self.file_menu.insertAction(self.file_menu.actions()[6], action)

def importFileToMyPlugin(self, filename=None):
    """Overrides Import file"""
    from myplugin.myplugin.plugins.plugin_module import MyPlugin

    self.loadPlugin(MyPlugin)

    self.addSheet()
    w = self.getCurrentTable()
    w.importMyPluginFile(filename, dialog=True)
    return
```

In the `importFileToMyPlugin` function, I set the default value of the `filename` parameter to `None`. However, at runtime, it seems to become `False`. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I ensure that the `filename` stays as `None` when it's not provided?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have looked at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56422390/22220653) that suggested using the @QtCore.pyqtSlot() decorator to avoid this issue but I'm not convicend that's the easiest solution.

Comment: Show us how you assert that the value is `False`.

Comment: The [`triggered`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) signal has a default argument corresponding to its checked state (even if the action isn't checkable) just like it happens with `clicked` for buttons. If you don't want that argument given in your function, either use the `pyqtSlot()` decorator without arguments (which *is* the easiest and correct solution for this case), use a lambda (`triggered=lambda: self.importFileToMyPlugin()`) or a separate function that calls the other without arguments. Alternatively, check the argument type: `if isinstance(filename, bool): filename = None`.